# Classification of crossed $G$-algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, group-cohomology, topological-quantum-field-theory, frobenius-algebras

*Added later*: As Viktor Ostrik points out in a comment, what I'm looking for is a classification of so-called crossed $G$-algebras corresponding to homotopy TQFTs with homotopy target space $K(G, 1)$ and functor target category $\operatorname{Vec}(\mathbb{C})$, which are defined on [the n-cat lab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/crossed+G-algebra), as well as in [Turaev's preprint from 1999](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910010.pdf) on page 14. As far as I can tell, those references do not provide a full classification though. Below the original question. I also added two axioms I originally had missed (thanks to Kevin Walker for pointing that out), and changed the title.

Consider a finite-dimensional (complex or real) algebra $A$ graded by a (finite) group $G$, i.e., a finite-dimensional vector space $V_g$ for every $g\in G$, and a linear map
$$ A_{g,h}: V_g\otimes V_h\rightarrow V_{gh}\;,$$
such that the overall algebra on $\bigoplus_g V_g$ is a symmetric Frobenius algebra. Furthermore, let there be a representation
$$\rho^h_g: V_h\rightarrow V_{g^{-1}hg}$$
of $G$ acting on $\bigoplus_h V_h$, such that
$$A_{h,i}\circ (\rho^{ghg^{-1}}_g\otimes \rho^{gig^{-1}}_g) = \rho^{hi}_g \circ A_{h,i}\;.$$
Also, we want $A$ to be graded-commutative, i.e.,
$$A_{g,h}\circ \tau = A_{h,h^{-1}gh}\circ (1\otimes \rho_h^g)\;,$$
where $\tau$ is the permutation map
$$\tau: V_h\otimes V_g\rightarrow V_g\otimes V_h\;.$$
Furthermore, we impose
$$\rho_g^g=1\;,$$
as well as the torus condition
$$\epsilon_g\circ(A_{ghg^{-1}h^{-1},hgh^{-1}}\otimes 1)\circ(1\otimes \rho^g_{h^{-1}}\otimes 1)\circ(1\otimes \eta_g)
=\\
\epsilon_h\circ(\rho^{ghg^{-1}}_g\otimes 1)\circ(A_{ghg^{-1}h^{-1}, h}\otimes 1)\circ(1\otimes \eta_h)\;,
$$
where $\epsilon$ is the Frobenius form and $\eta$ is its dual.

Also, for the instances I'm interested in, we can assume
$$A_{g,h} = \hat A_{g,h}^\dagger\;,$$
where $\hat A$ is the co-product of the Frobenius algebra,
$$ \hat A_{g,h}: V_{gh}\rightarrow V_g\otimes V_h\;.$$

What is the classification of those structures up to isomorphism? Have these structures or anything related been studied in the literature? If yes, can you give me the reference? Is there any established name for these structures?

The reason I'm interested in those structures is that they should correspond to 2-dimensional TQFT with group symmetries. Therefore, I expect the sub-classification where $\operatorname{dim}(A_h)=1$ for all $h$ to be via the second group cohomology $H^2(BG,U(1))$.

Comment: This seems to be related with Turaev's notion of crossed G-algebra, see Section 6 of his paper "Sections of fiber bundles over surfaces and TQFT's". It might be useful to note that (part of) your axioms can be restated as follows: you want a commutative algebra in representation category of the Drinfeld double of G.

Comment: Is your axiom for the compatibility of $\rho$ and $A$ too weak?  I would think you also need to relate
$A_{h,i}\circ (\rho^h_a\otimes \rho^i_b)$ to something (for distinct $a$ and $b$).

Comment: @KevinWalker: It's not impossible that I forgot some axioms. But I'm not sure about the axiom you suggest. If $a$ and $b$ are different, then one would also need one $A$ and two $\rho$s on the other side. Aren't those related to the axiom I included by simply adding the same $\rho^i_x$ on both sides? What did you have in mind to go on the other side?

Comment: I put a long answer below.

Comment: Another question: How do your axioms imply invariance of the path integral under "S" moves?  (i.e. decompose a punctured torus into a pair of pants (and an annulus) in two different ways)  Does this become more complicated than the $G=1$ case because of the annular (i.e. $\rho$) generators?  For "F" moves you can push $\rho$-annuli to the boundary and then use the associativity of the Frobenius algebra.  For "S" moves, it's not possible to push $\rho$-annuli to the boundary.

Comment: @KevinWalker: I'm confused by what you mean by an "S" move, even without any G-defects. I understand one can decompose a punctured torus into a pair of pants in two different ways, but in my world that does not yield a non-trivial axiom. If you think the other way round (which I do), then there is only one way to glue two boundary circles of the pair of pants, and that yields the punctured torus. Whether the mapping-class group of the punctured torus is non-empty doesn't matter, and does not produce any axioms (in the sense of non-trivial equations involving generators) in 2D TQFT. (continued)

Comment: The "F" move does produce a non-trivial axiom even though it's a mapping-class group element of the 4-punctured sphere, but only because it permutes the boundary circles. What the "S" move does yield though is a "tensor" or "generator" of 3D TQFT (3-2-1 extended). Are you maybe secretly thinking about the generators of 3D TQFT instead of the relations of 2D TQFT?

Comment: In other words, the cobordisms in 2D TQFT do not involve a homeomorphism to a "standard representative", only the 1D manifolds do. So automorphisms which do leave the boundary invariant do not contribute any axioms. However, in 3D TQFT, the 2D boundary manifolds do come with an identification with a canonical representative. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hmm, I just found [the relevant n-cat lab entry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/crossed+G-algebra), and what is called "torus condition" there does indeed sound very similar to your suggestion, in that it equates two punctured tori whose defect labels are related by an S transformation. Though I would say the decomposition of the torus into a pair of pants is the same on both sides and just the labels are different, but I guess that's merely a question of viewpoint. Is that what you meant? In that case please ignore my comments above!

Comment: Oh, and another axiom I forgot is $\rho_g^g=1$, since it is the same as the annulus with $g$ label "along" by twisting. Ironically, here I myself made the mistake I was talking about above: While the twist is non-trivial as a generator/tensor of 3-2-1-extended TQFT, it is trivial as a relation/axiom of 2-dimensional TQFT.

Comment: Yes, my question about "S-moves" is closely related to the torus condition in the nlab page.  The point is that you can start with two non-isomorphic $G$-pairs-of-pants and self-glue them to obtain two isomorphic $G$-punctured-tori.  Your $\rho_g^g = 1$ condition implies invariance under the $T$ generator of the mapping class group of the punctured torus, but invariance under the $S$ generator requires more.

Answer (score 2):

The classification of 2-dimensional TQFTs with G-action that I'm familiar with goes as follows.  Such TQFTs are equivalent to (1) a module category for the tensor category $Vec_G$; or, equivalently, (2) a 2-functor from $Vec_G$ to [1-categories, functors, natural transformations] (or to [1-categories, bimodules, bimodule maps]).

According to a theorem of Ostrik from around 2000, the above are classified (up to isomorphism) by pairs $(H, \omega)$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $\omega$ is a 2-cocycle on $H$.  (Two such pairs $(H, \omega)$ and $(H', \omega')$ are considered equivalent if $H'$ is conjugate to $H$, and this conjugation takes $\omega'$ to a cocycle cohomologous to $\omega$.)

The simple objects of the 1-category being acted upon correspond to cosets $G/H$.  In particular, actions on the trivial 1-category correspond to 2-cocycles on $G$, in accordance with your expectation.

---

Added later: The above is for fully extended TQFTs.  Perhaps you were asking about 2-level, not-fully-extended TQFTs?

Comment: Interesting, the data and classification you are describing is what I would use to describe 2-dimensional boundaries of the 3-dimensional untwisted Dijkgraaf-Witten state-sum for $G$. Do you know any reference where it is explained why this data corresponds to a 2D TQFT with G-action?

Comment: The sort of TQFT I'm describing is just ordinary 2D TQFT where all 1-manifolds and 2-manifolds are dressed by $G$-valued 1-cocycles. Then $A_{g,h}$ is just the pair of pants with a $g$-circle, a $h$-circle as input. $\rho^g_h$ is an annulus with a $h$-defect going round and a $g$-defect going along.

Comment: Just reading your addition: Exactly, I'm not talking about fully extended TQFTs but "ordinary" functors from 2-dimensional cobordisms (with G 1-cocycles) to vectorspaces.

Comment: Re your first question: In the fully extended case, it's just a matter of checking that the module category definition is equivalent to the 2-functor definition.  I haven't really thought about the not fully extended case, which is what I think you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to a question posed in the comments, not an answer to the original question.  (Too long to fit comfortably as a comment.)

Given a surface $Y$ (e.g. annulus or pair-of-pants), let $R(Y)$ denote the set of homomorphisms from the fundamental groupoid of $Y$ (with one basepoint in each boundary component) to $G$.

$R(S^1\times I)$ has the structure of a groupoid.  (Objects biject with $G$, morphisms from $g$ to $g'$ biject with $h$ such that $g' = h^{-1}gh$.)  Your representation $\rho$ captures this.

Let $P$ be the pair of pants.  The set $R(P)$ can be parameterized by $G^4$.  $R(P)$ affords an action of $C\times C\times C$, where $C$ is the groupoid $R(S^1\times I)$.  Your axiom for the compatibility of $\rho$ and $A$ captures only part of this trimodule structure on $R(P)$.

To reconstruct a general $G$-TQFT, I think you need to treat $R(P)$ is its full trimodule generality.  One way of saying this in your framework is to posit
$$
    A_{g,h}^{a,b}:V_g\otimes V_h\to V_{a^{-1}gab^{-1}hb}
$$
for all $g,h,a,b\in G$.  These $G\times G$-indexed tensor products need to intertwine with $\rho$ in three different places (trimodule).  Furthermore, the associativity constraint becomes more complicated to state.

(I see you have edited the $\rho$/$A$ compatibility axiom, but I still think you need more conditions on $\rho$ and $A$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still don't get it though. Are you suggesting to add $A^{a,b}_{g,h}$ as another generator? But isn't just $A^{a,b}_{g,h}=A_{a^-1ga,b^{-1}hb}\circ (\rho^g_a \otimes \rho^h_b)$, so you wouldn't need that generator?

Comment: I'm thinking of 2-manifolds dressed with "symmetry defects", i.e., thinking of the $G$ 1-cocycle as the dual $G$ 1-cycle and thus as $G$-labelled lines. Now take a 2-manifold decomposed into pairs of pants and tube segments. The pairs of pants I use only have defect lines "along" whereas the tubes also have defect lines "around". The overall 1-cohomology class fixes all the defect lines along. The equivalent configurations of lines around are all related by pulling "around" lines across any pair of pants, which is the axiom I stated (together with the representation axiom of $\rho$ alone).

Comment: OK, I now understand how you have organized things, and I agree that your revised $\rho$/$A$ compatibility condition seems sufficiently general.